# Configure Rails for ElasticSearch on an ubuntu remote server over https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, remote-access

My prod app (on an Ubuntu server) can't access my ElasticSearch server (on another Ubuntu server) over HTTPS.

My ES server is based on a proxy pass with Nginx with https and a basic auth. I can access it via https://elastic.myapp.com/, set my basic auth username/pass and get the ES response:

```
{
"name": "Cutthroat",
"cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
"version": {
"number": "2.0.0",
"build_hash": "ab54438d6af8f9340d50c5c786151783ce7d6be5",
"build_timestamp": "2015-10-22T08:09:48Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "5.2.1"
},
"tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My 4.2 rails app works well in local with ES on localhost:9200.

I used these gems:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

My 4.2 rails elasticsearch.yml config in production looks like:

```
host1:
  scheme: https
  host: elastic.myapp.com
  port: 443
  username: username
  password: password
```

My ruby connection file is:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: hosts, transport_options: { ssl: { ca_file: '/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem' } }
```

The error is:

```
(SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)
```

I don't know why cos' I have installed /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem on my Ubuntu 14.04 (installed on the server where is the Rails app, not the https ES server, is that right ?)

Note that if I change the connection to:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: hosts, transport_options: { ssl: { verify: false } }
```

it works... bu the SSL is not verified in production, too bad...

What did I miss on my Ubuntu servers ?

**Answer: In fact, I need top copy the SSL cert from the Elastic server to the App server, indicate the location to Elastic config and now it works.**